# In R why I can not show column content using for loop

Tags: r

Here is my question

I read a csv file and I want to out put every column one by one.

```
data=read.csv("C:/Users/tsong/prediction_data/agar-PUL-prediction-2018.01.24/growth-curve/figure-grofit/trash.csv",header=TRUE)

for (r in colnames(data)) {print (data$r)}
```

results are Null

Comment: Just do: `print(data[[r]])`

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I want to get the content of every column. And I confirmed that every column has a number list.

Answer (score 1):

`r` is a character. And the `$` does not handle characters in the way you hoped.

You should instead use `[[`

```
for (r in colnames(mtcars)) print(mtcars[[r]])
```

Comment: Thanks. newbie in R. Thanks for your help.